# SQL COUNT() statement not working

Tags: sql

I am trying to return the total number of reserved seats in my flightbooking table using a flightID number.

```
SELECT COUNT(flight.flightid) AS reservedseats FROM flightbooking
WHERE status=R
```

I get an error saying

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "flight"
>   LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(flight.flightid) AS reservedseats FROM flightbo...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need single quotes around `R`.  Then, you need to include `flight` in the `FROM` clause, if you are going to refer to it.  I think you need to study up a bit more on basic SQL syntax.

Comment: I know nothing about SQL

Comment: SELECT COUNT(flightbooking.flightid) AS reservedseats FROM flightbooking
WHERE status="R"

Comment: @Roy, single quotes for literals. (Double quotes are for delimited identifiers.)

Comment: it really helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(flight.flightid) AS reservedseats 
FROM   flightbooking AS flight
WHERE  status='R'
```

You were referring to `flight.flightid` but there isn't a table with name or alias `flight`. The engine doesn't know where it should retrieve `flightid` from.
You were also missing quotes around the char value `R`.

In your comment you say "I know nothing about SQL". It is much appriciated if you do some research yourself before you come here asking for help.

Comment: OK, i appreciate it. Thanks